# Filter out non-personal emails with Gmail filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to create an email filter in Gmail which moves all incoming messages which are not addressed to me (these are typically messages from mailing lists) to a folder named Lists. The filter dialog in Gmail seems quite limited. What I want is something like

```
-to:myemail -cc:myemail
```

Is there a way to create a filter from a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a filter from a query?

Yes. Write the query,  click on "Advanced search", then click on "Create filter":

[image]